# Can't programmatically hide UIButton created with IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

My iOS UIButton is correctly linked from IB to an IBOutlet in my view controller, as I can change its title from my code. Ie:

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //works
```

However,

```
[self.myButton setHidden:YES]; //doesn't work
//or
self.myButton.hidden = YES; //doesn't work
```

What's going on? How can I make myButton disappear?

**Update: some additional info**

Here's the code related in to my UIButton:

in my .h file

```
IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
-(IBAction)pushedMyButton:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *myButton;
```

in my .m file

```
@synthesize myButton;
- (void)pushedMyButton:(id)sender{
    self.myButton.hidden = YES;
}
- (void)dealloc{
    [self.myButton release];
}
```

Comment: code is correct.check some other things.

Comment: The code is correct (?) but I noticed one thing different to what I normally do.  Is it OK to define UIButton twice?  I usually say "@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *theButton;".  IBOutlet pre-compiles out to nothing, it's just a signpost to IB that you want to hook up that property to an IB entity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I found a workaround that works but I still don't know why my original code wasn't working in the first place. I used Grand Central Dispatch to dispatch a block containing the hide call on the main queue, like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myButton.hidden = YES; //works
});
```

Interesting. None of the initial code in my IBOutlet was wrapped in GCD blocks though. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem recently.   This may not be a "bug" in the Apple sense, but rather a changed behavior that we're not aware of.  What version of the SDK are you running?

Comment: I have the same - I just compiled a sample project and... it works.  So it's not a bug..?

Comment: Same here with the XCode 4.3.3... The thing is that all other buttons work fine, just this button I added doesn't. The only difference might be that this one does not have a texture but I simply put in some text...

Answer (score 5):

That should work, try rename it and hide it just to check that there aren't two buttons on top of each other.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and found the solution was to put the hidden in the right place, in my case  in the `viewDidLoad` function.

Comment: Jip, just did that too. Wanted to post it then saw you did :)

Comment: That's because all the iOS UIkit SDK methods (ViewDidLoad...) runs on Main thread!

Answer (score 3):

User Interface (UI) API (UIKit ...) methods have to be run on Main Thread!

So this will run on Main thread (as *dispatch_get_main_queue*):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.myButton.hidden = YES; //works
});
```

BUT usually we do something like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(hideButton) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)showButton
{
    myButton.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)hideButton
{
    myButton.hidden = YES;
}
```

As per Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html
"
**Threading Considerations**
Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView class from code running in the main thread of your application. The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread.
"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is putting the manipulating code in viewDidLoad instead of initWithNibName, like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    btnRestart.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: That's because all the iOS UIkit SDK methods (ViewDidLoad...) runs on Main thread!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem: button.hidden = YES didn't hide.

Solved it when I defined it in the .h file using @property and @synthesize in the .m file thus making it self.button.

Now self.button.hidden = YES works