# Can't hide programmatically created UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, programmatically-created

`LoginController` attempts a simple login try - if its successful, it calls `setEmail` in `leftcontroller`.

All I need to do when `setEmail` gets called is to hide the `btnLogin` and show the `buttonUser` and nothing I try is working.  The `NSLog`s get called and the `EventsController` loads so `setEmail` is working - it just won't hide and show the buttons.

`leftcontroller.h`:

```
@interface LeftController : UIViewController <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
    IBOutlet UIButton *buttonUser;
    NSString *setEmail;
}
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonUser;

@property(nonatomic,strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property(nonatomic) NSString *Email;

//-(void) setEmail : (NSString *) Email;

@end
```

`leftcontroller.m`:

```
- (void) setEmail : (NSString * ) Email{
    [buttonUser setTitle:Email forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //btnLogin.hidden = YES;
    //buttonUser.hidden = NO;
    [btnLogin setHidden:YES];
    [buttonUser setHidden:NO];

    NSLog(@"Set Email Called");
    NSLog(@"email: %@", Email);

    DDMenuController *menuController = (DDMenuController*)((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).menuController;
    EventsViewController *controller = [[EventsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

        [menuController setRootController:navController animated:YES];
} 

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = HEXCOLOR(0x000000);

    btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnLogin.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180.f, 48);
    [btnLogin setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnLogin addTarget:self action:@selector(LoginPressed)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnLogin.tag=1;

    btnLogin.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btnLogin setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnLogin.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);

    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_top.png"];
    [btnLogin setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:btnLogin];

    buttonUser = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    buttonUser.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180.f, 48);
    //[buttonUser setTitle:_Email forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonUser addTarget:self action:@selector(EmailPressed)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    buttonUser.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [buttonUser setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonUser.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);

    UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_top.png"];
    [buttonUser setBackgroundImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:buttonUser];
    buttonUser.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Is the button an outlet defined in your XIB or that variable in code or both?

Comment: no xib - I didn't think I needed the IBOutlet - just been trying different things to try to get it to work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498400/cant-programmatically-hide-uibutton-created-with-ib?rq=1

Comment: Just a note - you don't need to declare backing store variables for properties with any reasonably modern version of Xcode. Also, having a variable called `setEmail` is a bad idea. cf. KVO

Answer (score 4):

This line is suspect:

```
btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
// ...
[self.view addSubview:btnLogin];
```

If you are creating `btnLogin` and adding it to `self.view` yourself, in code, then *why is it an outlet?*

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
```

An outlet is for something that *already* exists and is instantiated in your *nib*. Hence it seems to me that you might have two `btnLogin` objects, with one of them wiping out your reference to the other. And the same for the other button.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting your properties, replace:

```
btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

with:

```
self.btnLogin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

And define your property like:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *btnLogin;
```

Do the same for `buttonUser`.

Comment: Why would you mark the property as an `IBOutlet` if the button is created in code?

Comment: My bad I meant to point out that it shouldn't be marked as an outlet, but forgot to remove that, thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `hidden` of your buttons, you are immediately saying

```
[menuController setRootController:navController animated:YES];}
```

This suggests that you are changing the interface. But if you are changing the interface, can you really tell whether your buttons have changed? I don't know what you're up to here, but perhaps your buttons are no longer in the interface. Maybe what you are seeing in the interface are a *different* set of buttons.

Comment: The leftcontroller (which is where the buttons are) is apart of https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController - a navbar button pulls out the menu, click on login (then login) and and load the events controller - the left controller never gets unloaded - it just hides

Comment: The buttons are in the left controller. If the left controller hides, how do you know the buttons are not changing? You can't see them any more.

Comment: Think the facebook ios app - the menu pulls out on click of the nav bar button - so after i hit login, i hit that nav bar button again and the login button hasen't become hidden